# Font top gets cut off when converting PSD to PDF

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, pdf

We used a lovely font across several PSD files (see image below) and are now ready to print (PDF).

[image: PSD file]

After saving as Adobe PDF, this is what we get (top of the G is cut off).

[image: PDF file]

After reading some articles and suggestions, increasing kerning was suggested. This, unfortunately, only fixes the issue for horizontal trimming, not vertical trimming.

When highlighting the text, this is what I see. I assume the area being cutoff is due to the actual space that the font occupies, but am not sure how to fix this.

[image: Font occupied space]

Any suggestions on how to fix this trimming conversion issue?

<sub>If you're looking for the font to test with, it's called Mowllnew and was retrieved [here](https://www.1001fonts.com/mowllnew-font.html).</sub>

Comment: Maybe try adjusting the baseline shift by a negative amount to move it down. You can do it in [the character panel](https://imgur.com/3e0gwEX)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rasterize that layer by right clicking on it in the *Layers* panel and choosing *Rasterize Type*. That will convert the type into a bunch of pixels, basically, a raster image.

Possibly duplicate the layer before this and hide the duplicate, in the event of future edits.

Answer (score 0):

Create Outlines...

Highlight the type layer and choose `Type > Convert To shape`.

Then it's a *vector shape* rather than live type. As a shape the entire path will be honored.

Comment: Hi Scott, just tried this, but same result. There are no other layers, just white background and text. Same happens for convert to smart object too.

Answer (score 0):

Just add conrol+shift in the beggining of the text.. problem solved

Comment: Hello Sagar. Welcome to GDSE, thanks for your answer. Could you [edit] the answer to include _why_ this is a solution to the problem and _how_ it works? Thanks, and keep contributing.